# how to show that $\tan^2 y=-\csc 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\csc y=\sin x -\cos x$ how to show that $\tan^2 y=-\csc 2x$

Can anyone explain to me? What identity I should use?

Comment: I got the answer $1/(2-\sin2x)$ why

Comment: Oops, I got my minus signs wrong! From $\sin^2 y+\cos^2 y=1$ we get $1+\cot^2 y=\csc^2 y$.  So $\cot^2 y=\csc^2 y-1$. Now everything should be good!

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** Show $tan^2(y) = -csc(2x)$, given that $csc(y) = sin(x) - cos(x)$.

**Identities/Knowledge:**

- $csc(\theta) = \frac {1}{sin(\theta)}$
- $sin(2\theta) = 2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$
- $cos^2(\theta) + sin^2(\theta) = 1$
- $tan(\theta) = \frac {1}{csc(\theta)cos(\theta)}$

**Working Out:**

Lets' begin with what the right hand side is equal too:

$$R.H.S = -csc(2x) = -\frac {1}{sin(2x)}$$
That was simple, now we move onto the left hand side (the fun part, I'll annotate as I go on):

$$L.H.S = \frac {sin^2(y)}{cos^2(y)} = (\frac {1}{csc(y)cos(y)})^2 $$

$$= \frac {1}{csc^2(y)cos^2(y)}$$
But $csc(y) = sin(x) - cos(x)$, so (***equation 1***);
$$ \frac {1}{(sin(x) - cos(x))^2 cos^2(y)}$$
Note that $cos^2(\theta) = 1 - sin^2(\theta)$
$$cos^2(y) = ? = 1 - (\frac {1}{sin(y)})^{-2} = 1 - (\frac {1}{\frac {1}{sin(y)}})^2$$
But $\frac {1}{sin(y)} = csc(y)$
$$ cos^2(y) = 1 - (\frac {1}{sin(x) - cos(x)})^2$$

Sub $cos^2(y)$ into ***equation 1***:
$$\frac {1}{(sin(x) - cos(x))^2 (1 - \frac {1}{(sin(x) - cos(x))^2})}$$
$$ = \frac {1}{(sin(x) - cos(x))^2 (\frac {(sin(x) - cos(x))^2 -1}{(sin(x) - cos(x))^2})}$$

Let $a = sin(x) - cos(x)$

$$\frac {1}{\frac {a^2(a^2-1)}{a^2}}$$
The $a^2$ cancels out, so you're left with:

$$\frac {1}{a^2 - 1}$$

But $a = sin(x) - cos(x)$

$$\frac {1}{(sin(x) - cos(x))^2 - 1}$$

Note that $(sin(x) - cos(x))^2 = cos^2(x) + sin^2(x) - 2sin(x)cos(x)$, but because of the identities listed above we can simplify it to; $1 - sin(2x)$.

$$\therefore \frac {1}{1 - sin(2x) - 1} = - \frac {1}{sin(2x)} = R.H.S$$

Answer (score 0):

Write
\begin{align}
-\csc2x
&=-\frac{1}{\sin2x}=\frac{1}{-2\sin x\cos x}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{(\sin x-\cos x)^2-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\csc^2y-1}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2y}{1-\sin^2y}
\end{align}